# Find a text between double quotation in ruby by gsub

Tags: regex, ruby, gsub

I wanna find a text in the text file by gsub in ruby and change it like this:

My text in main file:

```
set description "alas-cd002-ak"
```

And I wanna change it to below:

```
<desc>alas-cd002-ak</desc>
```

So I used below command but it didn't work:

```
text.gsub!(/\sset\sdescription\s"(?<name>^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$)"/,'<desc>\k<name></desc>')
```

Please help me fix my `gsub` code. also I'm new in Ruby.

Comment: Try `text.gsub!(/\bset\s+description\s+"([^"]+)"/,'<desc>\1</desc>')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its work, thanks a lot

Comment: Well, the first `\s` requires a whitespace before the `set` and the `^` and `$` anchors require the match of the `name` group pattern at the start and end of the line. You just need to remove these patterns from your regex and it will work.

Comment: What a warm feeling when a question is deleted, seemingly for no good reason, while one is working on an answer.

Comment: There is a very good reason for closing: OP inserted `^` and `$` by mistake. But for the lack of understanding what anchors are OP would have never posted the question.

Comment: @Wiktor, I don't understand why you closed it. The question is not why the OP's code doesn't work; it's how to convert the string in a particular way. Explaining the error in the OPs code --which you've done--is only part of an answer. You should post your comments in the form of an answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You should not reopen evident dupes. It adds no value to SO constantly repeating "remove the anchors" a billionth time.

Comment: @Wiktor, it is the question (here given by the title), not the SO's faulty technique in trying to solve it, that determines whether it's a dup. Replacing two double quotes with specified values may well be a dup, but no one has yet made that claim.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to use a regular expression, as @Wiktor has done in a comment. This is simply a demonstration of a way to use a regular expression with an enumerator.

```
str = "set description \"alas-cd002-ak\""

enum = ['<desc>', '</desc>'].cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["<desc>", "</desc>"]:cycle> 
str.gsub('"') { enum.next }
  #=> "set description <desc>alas-cd002-ak</desc>"
```

Note: `puts str` displays

```
set description "alas-cd002-ak"
```